# Javascript Regular Expression (x)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
var str = "foo xxx eee dsds";
var regex = /(foo)/;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

I expected output is:

> foo

But the actual output is:

> foo, foo

If i declare:

> var regex = /(foo)/g;

The output only is ***foo***

Can anyone help me? Thank for your help.

Comment: `match` returns an array. The first element of the array is the _whole match_ and the second one is the _captured_ output. In this case the values are the same. You want to the second element of the array. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Examples

Comment: so why /(foo)/g only return foo? @Vohuman

Comment: Because the ES standard says so: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10. By using the global flag the `match` method returns a different output, an array of matched values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second value in the array is the captured value, in absence of global modifiers `match` results contains the captured values. If you are removed the capturing group the result will only contains the match.

```js
var str = "foo xxx eee dsds";
console.log(str.match(/(foo)/));
console.log(str.match(/(foo)/g));
console.log(str.match(/foo/));
```

Check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Description) :

> *If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)*. The returned Array has an extra input property, which contains the original string that was parsed. In addition, it has an index property, which represents the zero-based index of the match in the string.
>
> *If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects*. Captured groups are not returned. If there were no matches, the method returns null.

Comment: Thank you, it is exact answer that i need

Comment: @ThiepLV :  glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your output is a return value of the `match` method [which is an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). To get the desired output, use either `str.match(regex)[0]` (the whole matched string) or `str.match(regex)[1]` (the captured substring matching `(foo)` which is the same in your case). But it's better to save the match array first and check if it is `null` or not (if the string doesn't match, it is `null` and `null[0]` will cause an error):

```
var match = str.match(regex);
if(match)
    console.log(match[0]);
else
    // do whatever you want when there's no match
```